# First project in Django gives me an error when I try to start it

Tags: python, django, powershell

I am a beginner in Python, especially in Django. I tried to use the `python manage.py runserver` command but it gave me an error. I have no ide why.

CMD:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command **python manage.py migrate**

Also I found that your error can be caused because you added an spanish character like an accent mark or an *ñ* if you delete it, the program should work.